# Does levelDB still corrupt data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, leveldb, nedb

I am writing a small NodeJS app, where I need a DB of some sort. LevelDB ([LevelUP](https://github.com/Level/levelup)) and [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) seams to be the most popular, so which to choose...

According to [Wikipedia on 18th Nov. 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB#Bugs_and_reliability), LevelDB often corrupt data.

> LevelDB is widely noted for being unreliable and databases it manages
>   are prone to corruption.[13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20] Academic
>   studies of past versions of LevelDB[21][22] have found that, under
>   some file systems, the data stored in those versions of LevelDB might
>   become inconsistent after a system crash or power failure. LevelDB
>   corruption is so commonplace that corruption detection has to be built
>   in to applications that use it.[23]

**Question**

Is this a thing from the past and is not an issue anymore?

Comment: I have used leveldb on windows quite extensively and never experienced any issues...

Comment: If you want resilience, SQLite is the most resilient local database, it is not 100% JS, but native implementations exist and are well maintained on all platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LevelDB is still notorious for unreliability and prone to corruption. There are quite [some](https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3Abug) issues still which need to be addressed.

NeDB seems like a better option IMO.

EDIT: Haven't used level DB in quite some while since writing this answer.